# Unable to download Ubuntu from the official website in Windows

Tags: downloads

I tried to download Ubuntu from the main website twice, even made a donation through PayPal, yet both times the download I expected didn't start. I was also not prompted where to do the download either.

What am I missing here? May it help to disable Windows firewall?

Comment: Try again but try pressing "not now, take me to download". If the download does not start, hit "download now" again.

Comment: I was trying to download Ubuntu.  It finally worked when I disabled Malwarebytes.  Thanks for your help, anyway.  Looking forward ot learning Ubuntu.

Comment: @Terre Good to hear that it worked out with your own solution. However, answers should not be posted as comments. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://askubuntu.com/privileges) to answer your own question, or to add actual comments when seeking clarification of any issues. I'll edit your question this time. Enjoy Ubuntu and feel free to ask more questions!

Comment: @gertvdijk Anyone can answer their own question, and anyone can comment on their own question or on answers to their own question. No amount of reputation is required for this.

Answer (score 2):

Try clicking on the 'Not now, take me to download' button.

[image]

If that still doesn't work it probably has something to do with the country your in.
See [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads) link for alternative downloads and other countries mirrors.